# Persistence of jQuery Mobile page loading message

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile and have turned off the default AJAX handling of forms and links, and I'm using

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()
```

to display the page loading message when I submit a form that transitions me to a different page. This works fine except for the fact that if I use the hardware back button on the device, or the browser's back button to go back to the form, the page loading message is still running. I've tried calling

```
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()
```

on document ready but this didn't seem to fire when I used the back button to go back.

Comment: have you tried calling `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()` right before you migrate back?

Comment: Are you explicitly deciding you want that back button? jQuery Mobile recently decided to not enable that by default. See: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/05/20/jquery-mobile-team-update-%E2%80%93-week-of-may-16th/ "Automatic toolbar back button: Now off by default"

Comment: @artlung Edited to state that I'm using either HW or browser back button, not the jqm one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be solved by listening to window unload and hiding the message there:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
 $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```

It seems like somewhat of a hack though.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$.mobile.pageLoading( true );`

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/methods.html

Show or hide the page loading message, which is configurable via `$.mobile.loadingMessage`.
Arguments:
Done (boolean, defaults to false, meaning loading has started). True will hide the loading message.

Examples:

```
//cue the page loader           
$.mobile.pageLoading(); 

//hide the page loader          
$.mobile.pageLoading( true );
```

Comment: These methods are being deprecated, but I tried those as well. The problem is that I don't seem to have proper opportunity to call these methods.

Comment: This is the latest supported build a4.1, so if you're using the test scripts you're on your own as they will most likely change from what they release. There is no use trying to debug test scripts that are not supported. I suggest you stick with the official releases. I think the beta release is coming soon so they might have a fix, new methods, a total re-write, etc...